# JQuery HTML onclick attribute on button not working after Ajax load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following button that is loaded from a PHP code via Ajax. The button has an onclick attribute to a function called viewImage. The Ajax request is made every 5 seconds, within the function loadImages.

Button from get.php page (not the full code, because I think it's not needed since I think it's a JQuery problem):

```
<button onclick="viewImage(<?php echo $imageID; ?>)" id="watch" class="btn btn-outline-warning">VIEW</button>
```

JS/Ajax Functions:

```
function viewImage(imageID) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./php/images/view.php",
    data: {imageID: imageID},
    success: function() {
        loadImage();
    }
  });
}

function loadImage() {
   $('#images').load('./php/images/get.php', function(){
     setTimeout(loadImage, 5000);
   });
};
```

The problem is, sometimes after the Ajax load, I can barely click on the button to be redirected to the function. I need to click a few times to work properly since the button keeps flashing/flickering, as you can see here

[image].

This only happens after a few (2 to 4) ajax loadings.

I removed the CSS styling to the buttons and it stopped flashing/flickering, but I still had to click on it a few times to it work.

All the files, functions and variables (eg. $imageID) are referenced correctly. Everything work, except this problem stated above.

Can someone help me?

Comment: This may be an issue with stacking timeouts.  Consider that every time you call `loadImages()` you are starting a logical recursive loop of calling load, and then calling the method again 5 seconds later.  So the first time that method is called, you have one logical loop.  Then, your images on click call viewImage, which as a success call loadImage.  So every time you click an images, you are starting one more logical loop, that is never being terminated.

Comment: I think this was the problem, didn't notice that. Putting `setTimeout` out from `loadImages()` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have an additional timeout in the `loadImage` function because it is only called after the server responded to the AJAX call, so the `loadImage` call should be synchronous. Adding the timeout will effectively make this call async and after multiple clicks, the async AJAX calls will start colliding with the async image loading calls - which is what you are observing